# Silverstripe 3 filter ArrayList

Tags: arraylist, filter, silverstripe

How can we filter an ArrayList in Silverstripe 3?

where getVideosfromCategories() returns a merged ArrayList

I need something Like:

```
$this->getVideosfromCategories()->filter('ID:LessThan', $id)->sort(array('ID' => 'DESC'))->first()
```

these Filters (filter('ID:LessThan', $id)) only work with DataList ?

How can i filter my ArrayList?

Comment: `ArrayList` and `DataList` both implement the `SS_Filterable` interface. You should be able to filter both in the same way. What is the exact problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> these Filters (filter('ID:LessThan', $id)) only work with DataList ?

Yep, that's correct, search filter modifiers only work on `DataList` instances. 
(https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/model/searchfilters/) It's interesting that the documentation does not mention that, I think it should be updated.

*(I opened a PR for it https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/pull/9363)*

But you can modify your current code to filter by an array of IDs instead, something like this:

```
$idsWeWant = [];
if ($id > 0) {
  $idsWeWant = range(0, $id - 1); // "$id - 1" because you had "LessThan" modifier.
}

$this->getVideosfromCategories()
  ->filter('ID', $idsWeWant)
  ->sort(array('ID' => 'DESC'))
  ->first();
```